Reading LazyListState leads to sporadic recompositions
Consider the following minimum reproducible code:
@Composable
fun Sandbox() {
    val state = rememberLazyListState()

    LazyColumn(
        state = state,
        modifier = Modifier.height(200.dp)
    ) {

        // This line of code leads to sporadic recompositions.
        // No recompositions once that line is commented out.
        val test = DoSomething(state)

        items(count = 50, key = {index -> index}) { index ->
            Text(text = "Item: $index")
        }
    }

}

fun DoSomething(state: LazyListState) : Int? {
    val items = state.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo
    return null
}

When I scroll the list up and down some times, that leads to recompositions:

As soon as I remove the call to DoSomething(state) I don't have that issue. Why does reading the state lead to recompositions?
Update:

Note that the items are recomposed, even though they are not touched. To my understanding of Compose they should be skipped.
When moving val test = DoSomething(state) out of LazyColumn, everything works as it should (Sandbox recomposes, LazyColumn gets skipped, items are not touched at all). However my question is not about how to get it working, but why it does not work as expected with calling val test = DoSomething(state) from the LazyColumn


What do you mean by "I want to return values (not possible with composable functions)"? Composable functions can return values, that's exactly what rememberLazyListState() does.

@GergelyKőrössy you are right, my mistake. I mixed it up with the error I would get in the case I would add @Composable in this special situation: "@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function". Seems like LazyListScope where I call this from is not a Composable scope.

@GergelyKőrössy added an update to my question. Can you answer the question?

What are you trying to achieve? I feel like this is an XY problem.

I am asking for learning purposes. I want to understand why reading state.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo leads to a recomposition of the items. To my current understanding they should be skipped / not recomposed.

The bounty attracted a ChatGPT (or similar) plagiariser (now deleted)

Value of state.layoutInfo changes every time you scroll or remeasure, as stated in this documentation.
You are accessing state.layoutInfo in the function. So it's natural that DoSomething will be called every time you scroll through the list. I don't know exactly why compose decides to recompose a composable that contains a function that always returns the same value. Maybe compose is not designed that way.
If you don't want recomposition but still need to use certain property of state.layoutInfo, then you should use derivedStateOf with LaunchedEffect. A good example is the following snippet:
@Composable
fun LazyListState.OnBottomReached(
    offset: Int = 0,
    loadMore: () -> Unit
) {
    val shouldLoadMore = remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            val lastVisibleItem = layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.lastOrNull()
                ?: return@derivedStateOf true
            lastVisibleItem.index >= layoutInfo.totalItemsCount - 1 - offset
        }
    }
    // Convert the state into a cold flow and collect
    LaunchedEffect(shouldLoadMore) {
        snapshotFlow { shouldLoadMore.value }
            .collect {
                // if should load more, then invoke loadMore
                if (it) loadMore()
            }
    }
}

Edit:
I observed that not only invocation of DoSomething happens quite randomly, but makes state.layoutInfo to change every time DoSomething is invoked.
So why this happens? In my observations, when instance of lambda function LazyListScope.content is recreated, it changes latestContent = rememberUpdatedState(content) value to change internally (Line 41). This somehow triggers LazyListState state to change, and that change triggers recreation of LazyListScope.content because it refers state.layoutInfo... on and on forever.
I don't know exactly how the compose runtime works, but I can see that this is not the correct way to use compose.
